# Jascript - Comparing 2 Arrays of Object in the fastest and cleaner way

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

Assuming we have 2 arrays, A (source) and B (being saved).

```
var A = [ 
      { id: 1, value: 'Product Name 1' },
      { id: 2, value: 'Product Name 2' },
      { id: 3, value: 'Product Name 3' },
      { id: 4, value: 'Product Name 4' },
      { id: 5, value: 'Product Name 5' } 
]


var B = [ 
      { id: 1, value: 'Product Name 1' },
      { id: 2, value: 'Changed Name' },
      { value: 'New Product' }
]
```

Basically what i want to do is to compare both arrays, and check on array B,  items are not present from array A which got deleted, the ones that had the 'value' property changed which got edited, and which ones are new which got added (basically without an id).

A logic goes like that (assuming that each A and B are one element from each array)

```
if A.id == B.id and A.value !== B.value then Edit

B.id doesnt exist then New

B.id is not on A then Deleted
```

I need to have a array of all the elements that got Added, Edited and Deleted

Expected Array would be

```
added = [ 
      { value: 'New Product'} 
]

edited = [ 
      { id: 2, value: 'Changed Name' }
]

deleted = [
      { id: 3, value: 'Product Name 3' },
      { id: 4, value: 'Product Name 4' },
      { id: 5, value: 'Product Name 5' } 
]
```

Comment: can you post your expected array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), like so

```
var A = [
    { id: 1, value: 'Product Name 1' },
    { id: 2, value: 'Product Name 2' },
    { id: 3, value: 'Product Name 3' },
    { id: 4, value: 'Product Name 4' },
    { id: 5, value: 'Product Name 5' }
]

var B = [
    { id: 1, value: 'Product Name 1' },
    { id: 2, value: 'Changed Name' },
    { value: 'New Product' }
]

// deleted
var deleted = A.filter(function (a) {
    return !B.some(function (b) { return b.id === a.id })
})
var changed = A.filter(function (a) {
    return B.some(function (b) { return (b.id === a.id) && (b.value !== a.value) })
})
var added = B.filter(function (b) {
    return !A.some(function (a) { return b.id === a.id })
})

console.log(deleted);
console.log(changed);
console.log(added);
```

The `changed` array currently returns the A elements, if you want B's elements, just swap A and B in that bit of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this (example uses [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs) utility library):

```
var create = _.cloneDeep(A);
var delete = _.cloneDeep(B);
var edit = _.remove(create, function(c) {
    return _.some(delete, function(d, dIndex) {
        if (c.id === d.id) {
            d.splice(dIndex, 1);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can directly use like

```
 result = [];
for(var index in  A) {
    var item = A[index],index1;
    for(index1 in B) {
        var item1 = B[index1];
        if(item1.id == item.id ) {
            result.push(item1);
            break;
        }
    }
    if(index1 == B.length-1) 
        result.push(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) + [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) (ES6)

```
var result = { new: [], edited: [], deleted: [] };

result = B.reduce(function (l, r) {
    if (typeof r.id === "undefined") {
        l.new.push(r);
    } else {
        var elementInA = this.find(function (el) {
            return el.id === r.id;
        });

        if (typeof elementInA === "undefined") {
            l.deleted.push(r);
        } else if (elementInA.value !== r.value) {
            l.edited.push(r);
        }
    }

    return l;
}.bind(A), result);    // .bind(A) to get the <A> array available as <this> in the reduce callback.
                       // Of course A.find instead of this.find would also be possible

console.log(result);  // {"new":[{"value":"New Product"}],"edited":[{"id":2,"value":"Changed Name"}],"deleted":[]}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4w5udbj8/)